# What does this lock icon mean in dreamweaver file explorer

Tags: jquery, html, ide, dreamweaver

[image]

That mean it's zipped or somethign? or that mean it is locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A lock symbol appears beside the local file’s icon indicating that the
>   file is now read-only.

**Look at adobe forum:** http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7eb9a.html

Answer (score 2):

The lock symbol indicates that the file is read-only (Windows) or locked (Macintosh).